# Why am I getting a clang error when compiling ruby-1.9.3-p125?

Tags: ruby, macos, compiler-errors, osx-lion, rvm

I just installed Ruby 1.9.3-p194 by running

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

And it got installed with no problem.

Now when I want to install 1.9.3-p125 I get this error message:

```
rvm install 1.9.3-p125 --with-gcc=clang
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/foo/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/foo/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/foo/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Compiling yaml in /Users/foo/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Installing yaml to /Users/foo/.rvm/usr
clang: error: unsupported option '--with-libyaml'
```

But the installation proceeds and 1.9.3-p125 gets installed in the end.

Any ideas why am I getting `clang: error: unsupported option '--with-libyaml'` and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Why the `--with-gcc=clang` option? I installed 1.9.3-p125 like so:

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p125
```

Have you tried it without that option specified?

Not sure if this makes a difference for you, but you may want to review this recent pull request that was processed into rvm -- it may be relevant.

https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/pull/869

Comment: Did you upgrade to XCode from an earlier version? In that case --with-gcc=clang is not needed. But if you clean installed XCode 4.3 and do not have GCC installed manually you'll need the clang option.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I just installed the developer tools directly from the the app store link.